# scrolIntoView with behavior smooth in react js not working in mobile

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a smooth scrollIntoView using refs of react. In the browser of a desktop computer it's working as expected. However, when I open it using mobile browser (e.x Safari) it scrolls to the section I want but not smoothly. Can you help me figure out this problem?

My code :

```
class BrandView extends React.Component<Props> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
  }

  ON_CLICK_ALPHABETIC_ITEM = (index: string) => () => {
    this.refs[index].scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  render() {
    const { brandList, brandSortedByAlphabetic, loading } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <AlphabeticBar {...{ brandSortedByAlphabetic }} onClickItem={this.ON_CLICK_ALPHABETIC_ITEM} />
        {brandList.brandList.map((item, index) => (
          <div className="brandItem" key={index} ref={index}>
            <div className="brandInfo">
              <div>
                <img alt="brand-logo" src={`${mediaUrl}/${item.image}`} />
              </div>
              <div>
                <div className="brandTitle">
                  <Link to={"/brand/" + item.brand_id}>
                    <label>{item.brand_name}</label>
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="brandDescription">
                  <label>{item.short_bio}</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="products">
              {item.products.map((product_item, product_index) => (
                <div className="product" key={product_index}>
                  <Link
                    to={
                      product_index === item.products.length - 1 && item.items > 0 ? "/brand/" + item.brand_id : "/product/" + product_item.product_id
                    }>
                    {product_index === item.products.length - 1 && item.items > 0 ? (
                      <div>
                        <div className="overlay-div">
                          <p className="shop-all">SHOP ALL</p>
                          <p className="item-number">{item.items} items</p>
                        </div>
                        <img alt="brand-products" src={product_item.image} />
                      </div>
                    ) : (
                      <img alt="brand-products" src={product_item.image} />
                    )}
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would share the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @MartinReicheI added :D

Answer (score -1):

Maybe just use a library that is able to handle all of that both in mobile as well as in desktop browsers like react-scroll: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll

If you do not want to use third-party libraries, please share the relevant parts of your code, so people can actually see what you have done so far.

Comment: I added to this question :d